# C# Finding specific strings in a sentence and storing in a multidimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, foreach, find

Basically,

- there's a list of sentences.
- there's a list of entities (basically specific words)
- sql query in another method to insert in to a database

I'm looking for a way to loop through the sentences and check if any 'entities' that are declared in the list are found in each sentence. If they are then add them to perhaps a multidimensional array where entities could be stored in the format of sentences and pass them to the Sql query method.

As of now, this is what I have:

```
        List<string> sentenceList = new List<string>(new String[]
{"Gerald has a nice car", "Rachel has a cute cat"});

        List<string> entityList = new List<string>(new String[] 
{ "Gerald", "car", "Rachel", "cat" });

        foreach (string sentence in sentenceList)
        {
            string currentSentence = sentence;

            foreach(string entity in entityList)
                if (currentSentence.Contains(entity))
                {
                   This is where I need help with the code :)
                   //Add them as strings or an array and pass them to the method
                   //to be added in to table columns
                }
```

Basically like:

> Gerald has a nice car
>
> Rachel has a cute cat

Should be stored as:

> Gerald, car
>
> Rachel, cat

Is there any way I can add each entity in a sentence to a list or an array or a set of strings for each sentence, like displayed in the above output example? (in a row)

The '.Contains' could work but any alternate algorithms are also welcome :) Thank you in advance

Comment: What is your question exactly? it looks like you already have the solution? (btw, the currentSentence variable isn't needed)

Comment: I need to code my way through adding them to an array such that each entity in a sentence could be added to a table entry for each sentence @Sayse

Comment: Ah so your struggling with the commented bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following linq should help:

```
List<string> sentenceList = new List<string>(new String[]
{"Gerald has a nice car", "Rachel has a cute cat"});

        List<string> entityList = new List<string>(new String[] 
{ "Gerald", "car", "Rachel", "cat" });

foreach (string sentence in sentenceList)
{
    var words = sentence.Split(" ".ToCharArray());
    var valid_words = words.Where (w => entityList.Any (en_li => en_li.Equals(w)));
    // do something with valid_words. It's an enumerable with the words that match.
}
```

Will get you

> for Gerald has a nice car
>   IEnumerable (2 items)
>   Gerald  car
>
> for Rachel has a cute cat
>   IEnumerable (2 items)
>   Rachel  cat

Comment: Sir, what reference is needed to use the .dump? Currently facing an error that says 'does not contain a definition for dump'

Comment: Lol ... sorry ... you can remove the `.Dump()`. It's from linqpad, and used as a `WriteLine`. I'll remove it from the answer

Comment: Thank you, this worked :) Thanks for all the answers as well!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing in arrays, you would be better off with lists again since they aren't fixed size

```
List<string> sentenceList = new List<string>(new String[]
    {"Gerald has a nice car", "Rachel has a cute cat"});

List<string> entityList = new List<string>(new String[] 
    { "Gerald", "car", "Rachel", "cat" });

List<List<string>> allSentenceEntities = new List<List<string>>();
foreach (string sentence in sentenceList)
{
    List<string> currentList = new List<string>();

    foreach(string entity in entityList)
        if (currentSentence.Contains(entity))
            currentList.add(entity);
    if(currentList.Any())
        allSentenceEntities.Add(currentList);
{
```

Obligatory linq answer

```
var allSentenceEntities = 
      sentenceList.Select(s => entityList.Where(e => s.Contains(e)).ToList())
                  .ToList();
```

In response to Victors answer - you can search for `string.Format(" {0} ", entity)` (the word surrounded by spaces) to avoid picking up erroneous words

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list of entities is fixed, that you're looking for better performances and that you have many entities, then a pretty cheap yet efficient solution would be to:

  a) Put all of your entities into a SortedList.

b) Splits your sentence through string.Split.

c) For each word of your sentence, use SortedList.Contains

And this could be further refined by using a manual words lookup rather string.Split and a mere array with a manual dichotomous lookup rather than a SortedList. The point would be to avoid the allocation of one string per word.

Note also that your current algorithm has a flaw as it does not respect words boundaries: for example it will match "CATegory" for "cat".

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a HashSet for entities as it provides O(1) lookup.

```
    var sentenceList = new List<string>(new String[] { "Gerald has a nice car", "Rachel has a cute cat" });
    var entityList = new HashSet<string>(new String[] { "Gerald", "car", "Rachel", "cat" });

    var a = sentenceList.Aggregate(new List<List<string>>(),
        (lst, str) =>
        { 
            lst.Add(str.Split(' ').Where(x => entityList.Contains(x)).ToList());
            return lst; 
        },
        x => x.Where(y => y.Count > 0).ToList());
```